# Traveling Salesman (TSP) with defined start and end points visualized by network

Tags: r, algorithm, traveling-salesman, directed-graph

I would like to generated a directed network from a distance matrix where edges connect nearest vertices, or vertices that minimize the distance between the nodes. Each point, other than the start and end points, on the network would have a incoming edge and outgoing edge. Each point should be hit only once. I should also mention that I have defined START and END points. I believe this is similar to solving the traveling salesman problem (TSP).

Distance matrix:

```
         A        B         C         D         E
A    0.000 1975.317 1170.9915 1106.5238 1022.9888
B 1975.317    0.000 1977.8852 1689.8195 1762.5819
C 1170.991 1977.885    0.0000  962.0281 1073.0755
D 1106.524 1689.820  962.0281    0.0000  975.8099
E 1022.989 1762.582 1073.0755  975.8099    0.0000
```

Corresponding dendrogram can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wrqdq.png), although I'm not sure how this will relate to the network since we will have defined start and end states. For this example we have:

START point: `E`

END point: `A`

Ultimately I would like to produce a network that looks something like this:

```
E --(975.8)--> D --(962.0)--> C --(1977.9)--> B --(1975.3)--> A
```

Edge weights, here depicted within the parentheses, are the distances between two points. The way I think this need to be approached is to loop through each column, beginning with the START point, take the minimum value, add the corresponding vertex to that value, remove that value from the matrix and continue until the END point is reach. If the END point is reached before the end, skip it and take the second lowest value. Perhaps there is a better way to go about this? I've looked into the network library but have no experience with this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Simple observation:  your proposed algorithm cannot be correct as you may get different answers depending on the order of the columns in your loop.

Comment: @BadZen, sorry I don't follow. We have a defined START position and END position. We can fill in the intermediate positions by preforming a sort of traceback, no?